# Saving to file from pgadmin4

Tags: pgadmin-4

I am using PGadmin4.  My developers went on holiday.  If I pose my question using the query input page I get error messages like: JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint con ON con.conrelid=rel.oid    But I can place the same queries from the 'command line'.  My problem is that I generate thousands of lines and need to direct output to a file (running on a Mac).  Is there a way to do this?

I tried to use the Query tool. Did not work and tested the psql tool - but need to divert output to a file.

Comment: In command line append `> outputfilename.txt` after your psql call for example.

Comment: Tried that and from the command line in PGadmin4 it does not give an error message - perhaps there is a .txt file on the server where the database is ??  But - on my Mac where I am running PGadmin there is no file.